# Trying to find Shipibo-Conibo-Shetebo ethnic group music “Icaro chants”

Tags: identify-this-genre, choral-music, vocal-styles

Recently i found an album of David Darling called Mudanin Kata made in collaboration with indigenous people from Taiwann

Now I am trying to find something similar, but from people who lived in Peru region in particular Shipibo-Conibo-Shetebo ethnic group.

What did i found that i am looking for the Icaro chants (how they call it) which are performed for example during the nightly healing rituals of the Ayahuayqueros.

So I am trying to find some Icaro chants music well recorded as in the Mudanin Kata album.